# Top 20 spending category FORMULA

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm using Google Sheet for a annual badget tracking.
I'm trying to figure out how sort 20 top categories from a specific range (categories and prices) but i get an error all the time and i can't understand what i'm doing wrong.

This is my formula and where I stuck:

=SORTN(UNIQUE(FILTER(FLATTEN(P21:P40,W21:W40,I46:I65,P46:P65,W46:W65),FLATTEN(P21:P40,W21:W40,I46:I65,P46:P65,W46:W65 <>"")),20,0,FILTER(FLATTEN(T21:T40,AC21:AC40,N46:N65,T46:T65,AC46:AC65),FLATTEN(P21:P40,W21:W40,I46:I65,P46:P65,W46:W65)<>""),0,1,1)

seems the problem coming from the second part:
FILTER(FLATTEN(T21:T40,AC21:AC40,N46:N65,T46:T65,AC46:AC65),FLATTEN(P21:P40,W21:W40,I46:I65,P46:P65,W46:W65)<>""),0,1,1)

[image]

[image]

This is the error i got:
Error
FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 60. column count: 1. Actual row count: 100, column count: 1.

Could please anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I think your formula should have been

```
=SORTN(UNIQUE(FILTER(FLATTEN(P21:P40,W21:W40,I46:I65,P46:P65,W46:W65),FLATTEN(P21:P40,W21:W40,I46:I65,P46:P65,W46:W65 <>""))),20,0,FILTER(FLATTEN(T21:T40,AC21:AC40,N46:N65,T46:T65,AC46:AC65),FLATTEN(P21:P40,W21:W40,I46:I65,P46:P65,W46:W65)<>""),0,1,1)
```

I can't prove this definitively without test data, but the missing 40 rows are almost certainly because your sheet only goes up to column Z so AC21:AC40 and AC46:AC65 aren't included. If you insert more columns to the right without changing the formula, the error goes away.

Comment: I tried your formula and this is the error i got back:
Error
SORTN has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 3. column count: 1. Actual row count: 25, column count: 1.
I added a picture so you can see datas.

Comment: That would be because of Unique - if there is some repetition in columns P, W etc. you are going to get a lower total.

Comment: I'm tring everything, and it's like something wrong after second filter, after unique too:
FILTER(FLATTEN(T21:T40,AC21:AC40,N46:N65,T46:T65,AC46:AC65),FLATTEN(P21:P40,W21:W40,I46:I65,P46:P65,W46:W65)<>""),0,1,1)
any suggesitons?

Comment: I can only give general suggestions because no-one is going to type in all that data, and I can't seem to match up the columns in the formula with the picture. I would start by taking out the unique altogether - this at least seems to give some results, but I've only put in a few numbers to try it =ArrayFormula(SORTN(FILTER(FLATTEN(P21:P40,W21:W40,I46:I65,P46:P65,W46:W65),FLATTEN(P21:P40,W21:W40,I46:I65,P46:P65,W46:W65 <>"")),20,0,FILTER(FLATTEN(T21:T40,AC21:AC40,N46:N65,T46:T65,AC46:AC65),FLATTEN(P21:P40,W21:W40,I46:I65,P46:P65,W46:W65)<>""),0,1,1))

Comment: Seems the second part, start from FILTER as something wrong.
I add new images, maybe this could help you to understand better

Comment: OK last one - sorry but you can only expect answers to one question, not a whole series of them plz see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask This time it's because some of the ranges in the second part of the filter extend across two columns so you have S11:S30 (20 cells) AA11:AB30 (40) S36:S40 (5) AA36:AB40 (10) making a total of 75 cells.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't want to break any rules, I thought this was the same problem so I asked again. In any case I found the problem, as you mentioned in the last answer, I got one column merge to another so the count was wrong, I deleted one column so every cell now lives in one column and the count is correct and everything is working pretty well. I apologize again and again thank you very much for the help.

Comment: No problem - glad we got there in the end.